# Gatsby Schema Depracation Warning: Inferred Resolvers

Tags: javascript, node.js, graphql, schema, gatsby

In my graphQL schema in gatsby, I am getting a deprecation notice about inferred resolvers.  When I declare a list, this is my syntax:

```
List: [List]
```

And then outside of that node, I define it as such.

```
 List: `
     subfield1: String
     subfield2: String
      `,
```

I have attempted adding the @link(from: "...") extension to remove this deprecation notice, but nothing seems to work, either the node isn't fetched correctly or I still get the deprecation notice.
Here is the actual deprecation notice:

```
warn Deprecation warning - adding inferred resolver for field ...
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you might be getting this deprecation warning because there is no `@infer` or `@dontInfer` in your type definition. It's hard to say though without more code.

Here is an example of what worked for me:

```
exports.createSchemaCustomization = ({
  actions: { createTypes }
}) => {
  const myFirstType = 'someTypeName';
  const mySecondType = 'someOtherTypeName';
    const typeDefs = `
      type ${myFirstType} implements Node @dontInfer{
        id: String
        filesArray: [File]
        trueOrFalse: Boolean
        aSpecialDate: Date
      }
      type ${mySecondType} implements Node @infer{
        date: Date @dateformat
        singleFile: File @fileByRelativePath
        authorByEmail: Author @link
      }
    `;
    createTypes(typeDefs);
}
```

References: I started here https://github.com/panr/gatsby-starter-hello-friend/pull/10 which got me here https://www.gatsbyjs.com/blog/2019-05-17-improvements-to-schema-customization/#migrating-your-code

**PS.** I should point out that I'm completely new to GraphQL and Gatsby's "internal workings". This solution resolved the deprecation warnings for me. Hopefully it can help anyone else struggling with the whole GraphQL schema customisation.